# How do I remove a part of a name that os.walk shows?

Tags: python, os.walk

So I have a lot of directories and don't want to click each one to see what files are in there. So I made a short script which makes it easier for me. The only problem I have is that some file names are super long. Is there a way I can shorten the output of the names? Here's the code

```
path = 'G:/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                    for name in files:
                        print(os.path.join(root, name, '\n')
```

can I remove the last like 10 letters of the output?

btw sorry if I made this wrong its my first time posting here...

Comment: You can slice the string. For eg: `os.path.join(root, name, '\n')[20:]` to just show string upto 20 characters (rest of chars will be skipped during printing)

Comment: Similarly `[:-10]` would slice 10 characters off the end of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to slice the output only if it's **super long**:

```
maxLen = 85
for name in files:
    pathname = os.path.join(root, name, '\n')
    if len(pathname) > maxLen:
        #Trims the string only if it's longer than maxLen
        pathname = pathname[:maxLen]+"..." #Trailing dots indicate that has been trimmed
    print(pathname)
```

Or, as suggested by [@Cory Kramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458/cory-kramer), you could just trim the string:

```
print(os.path.join(root, name, '\n')[:-10]) #Removes the last 10 characters in every case
```